# VLClib error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, vlc, libvlc

I used VLClib in my C# code to play a RTSP Stream. and OpenCV in C++ for some processes on this stream's frames.
in Output window, I got this messages:

```
core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 300 ms)
core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
```

And after that, every time I have some problem like `Attempted to read or write protected memory` on exactly the line that called my OpenCV code. which I don't know if they related to this messages or not.

But anyway, what is the meaning and cause of these messages?
I searched, but most of the result was about VLC player and its problem with DVDs.

this is my whole logs:

```
Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.  
Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.  
[1074ff1c] core vout display error: Failed to set on top  
[1074ff1c] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR  
[19ac8a0c] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom  
[19ac8a0c] core vout display error: Failed to set on top  
[19ac8a0c] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR  
[19ac8a0c] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom  
[19ac8a0c] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR  
The thread '<No Name>' (0x173c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).  
[1088902c] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom  
[1088902c] core vout display error: Failed to set on top  
[1088902c] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR  
[04e60e54] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 300 ms)  
[04e60e54] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called  
[1088902c] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom  
[1088902c] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR
```

Answer (score 5):

Those messages come from the access module of VLC where it is complaining about corruptions in your stream. If you were playing local content, this would be an indications that your files are bad. For streaming content, this is pretty normal especially when using WiFi as packets can get lost. It is generally save to ignore those errors.

The video display errors are from the video output core, since you are deploying a video output module which does not said features, which again, is absolutely non-problematic. Those errors are provided so you are not surprised that certain features won't work.

Comment: the video is running perfectly fine ,so it seems its not corrupt , but through my software inbuilt vlc player its not working